# Sklearn inverse transform LabelBinarizer for only one encoded value

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have successfully encoded my data like this:

```
reviewerLe = LabelBinarizer()
reviewerIDs = reviewerLe.fit_transform(df['reviewerID'])
```

and

```
print(reviewerIDs[1])
reviewerIDs[1].shape
```

outputs

```
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
(4975,)
```

I am wondering how to inverse transform only one or a couple of predicted values.

```
reviewerLe.inverse_transform(reviewerIDs[1])
```

outputs

```
axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

I don't quite understand what the function exprects. In the docs is stated :

> inverse_transform(Y, threshold=None)
> Y{ndarray, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_classes)

> Target values. All sparse matrices are converted to CSR before inverse transformation.

Does that mean that i should reshape my array to (1,4975)? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inverse_transform() expects a 2D array, but you're passing a 1D array to it.

You can reshape your 1D array into a 2D

```
reviewerIDs_2D = reviewerIDs[1].reshape(1, -1)
reviewerLe.inverse_transform(reviewerIDs_2D)
```

Comment: Posted at the same time as you, marking your answer as correct. How does the minus 1 work exactly?

Comment: -1 is used when you want the program to automatically calculate the size of a particular dimension.

In your case (1,-1) and (1,4975) are same

Answer (score 0):

I needed to reshape the array.

```
new_arr = reviewerIDs[1].reshape(1,reviewerIDs[1].size)
reviewerLe.inverse_transform(new_arr)
```